# I want to change to Dynamic SQL Query instead of CASE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I have two tables as below and description is given in below

**Employee table**

```
id EmployeeID   departmentid department1   department2 department3 
1    300            100           IT          Finance     
2    400            101           IT          Sales
3    500            102           Technology  Finance 
4    600            101           IT                       HWD
```

**Department table**

```
id  EmployeeID departmentkeys Departmnetvalues
100     300      1                      IT
101     400      1                      IT
102     500      2                      Finance
103     600      1                      IT
```

In `department` table, i have `departmentkeys` column that contains the values `1,1,2,1` and maps to column `department1`,`department2`,`department3` in the `Employee` table .

- `1` means `department1`
- `2` means `department2`
- `3` means `department3`

I want to fetch record based on matching records from `employee` and `department` 
table.

```
select * from Employee e
inner join department d on e.departmentid=d.id
and Case
  When d.departmentkeys=1 then e.department1
  When d.departmentkeys=2 then e.department2 
  When d.departmentkeys=3 then e.department3
End=d.departmentvalues
```

I do not want to to use CASE statement because its causing a performance issue. Instead of CASE statement i want to use SQL Dynamic query .

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Dan Guzman](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/44434/dan-guzman) in the comments, you can do this with `UNION ALL` instead of dynamic SQL:

```
select * 
from Employee e
    inner join department d 
        on e.departmentid=d.id
where d.departmentkeys=1 AND e.department1 = d.departmentvalues

UNION ALL

select * 
from Employee e
    inner join department d 
        on e.departmentid=d.id
where d.departmentkeys=2 AND e.department2 = d.departmentvalues

UNION ALL

select * 
from Employee e
    inner join department d 
        on e.departmentid=d.id
where d.departmentkeys=3 AND e.department3 = d.departmentvalues;
```

[Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) mentioned another option, which is to use multiple left joins to the same table.

This has the possibility of producing different results if there are any employees that don't have a department, and `UNION ALL` is probably a better option, performance-wise here.  But this is the general approach for the multiple join option:

```
select * from Employee e
left join department d1 
    on e.departmentid=d1.id and d1.departmentkeys=1 and e.department1=d1.departmentvalues
left join department d2
    on e.departmentid=d2.id and d2.departmentkeys=2 and e.department2=d2.departmentvalues
left join department d3
    on e.departmentid=d3.id and d3.departmentkeys=3 and e.department3=d3.departmentvalues
```